# 2012 SharePoint Conference November 12-15 in Las Vegas!

Tags: discussion, conferences, community

If you watch your twitter at all, I'm sure you've seen this already:
http://www.mssharepointconference.com/Pages/default.aspx

Anyone thinking about going?

Registration starts in the middle of May.

Answer (score 1):

I intend to go. I went to SPC09 in 'Vegas and it was an incredible week. The conference wasn't bad either ;-)

Comment: Hmm... never been to Vegas so this might be worth it. :)

Comment: Let me know if you are going so we can link up this time.

Answer (score 1):

I'll definitly be there. This will be THE conference to get good information about SharePoint15 before it RTMs.

Answer (score 1):

I will be there too along with my colleague [Per Jakobsen](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/users/990/per-jakobsen):)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't miss this conference for anything!  It is the only time that you get all of the Microsofties, MVPs, community leaders and SharePoint community members in the same place at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If my company sponsored me I would also definitely go. But, I am not that fortunate :(

Answer (score 0):

This week was FANTASTIC! Great sessions, and they simply but on an AMAZING week. ZERO complaints about the conference in anyway.

Comment: I'm jealous.. :)